# How it's made: svg graphs controlled by scrollbar

Tags: graph, interactive

NYT has just produced this nice chart animation, any idea what tech is behind it?

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/03/31/science/motorcycle-helmet-laws.html?_r=0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pretty classical D3 stuff (using SVG under the hood). Not sure how the scroll bar business works, but I see that it doesn't work in IE11, so it probably is library-driven rather than native SVG/JavaScript that generally works well across browsers. The underlying technology of the curve-interpolation can either be done using SMIL (the natural way) or through JavaScript, but interpolating the values of control points of Bezier curves (either quadratic or cubic.) See 
http://cs.sru.edu/~ddailey/svg/2011/reshaping.html for examples or curve interpolation. You'll note that Firefox still doesn't handle the second animation on this page, but I suppose I never got around to filing a bug. It should work everywhere else though (except for IE since they don't do SVG/SMIL).